Finding phase center of antenna simulated with 4nec2
I am trying to simulate a helical antenna for 1.7GHz and would like to extract the phase centre so I can correctly mount it at the focal point of my dish.
But I do not know where to find this or how to compute it. In the nec output, I only found phase data for every element.
Thank you for your help.
This is the output of the nec file:
SEG.  TAG    COORD. OF SEG. CENTER     SEG.            - - - CURRENT (AMPS) - - -
 NO.   NO.     X        Y        Z      LENGTH     REAL        IMAG.       MAG.        PHASE
    1    1   0.0000  -0.1361   0.1484  0.02474   2.3165E-03  1.3392E-04  2.3203E-03    3.309 



In the nec output, I only found phase data for every element.

The element's phase is relative to excitation, so useless for us; also, the phase center will probably not be on an element.
You want the phase center, extracted from a 3D E-field vector field.
That's not something that's built in to 4nec2 (or any NEC2-based antenna simulator I'd know).
NEC2 can't give you absolute phase counts from the feed – it can, at best, calculate the phase of the E-field (or H-field, doesn't matter) modulo $2\pi$ (i.e., assuming an infinitely long harmonic excitation) – but for a directive antenna like a helical antenna, that's not going to be sufficient to actually describe phase center, because it makes a huge difference of your wave has phase (just a stupid example) $0.787 \pi$ or $2.787\pi$.
The only thing you can do with such a simulator is take a small segment in space "in front" of your antenna, where you're confident the phase doesn't change more than $\pi$, simulate the near field E-field in that, which would be a complex field, extract the argument of these complex values in 3D space, fit a surface of constant phase and say "this is the apparent phase center for a small range of directions going from the apparent phase center through the center region of my simulated volume".
So, use the raw NEC2 output, save it to a table/CSV file, write octave/matlab/python/C++/julia to try to fit concentric circles through the far-field directions of equal phase: the common center of your circles is your phase center, if it exists; this is not guaranteed due to the $2\pi$ ambiguity. You would then need to select a smaller range of angles (and configure 4nec2 to raster these finer), and repeat.
Frankly, lacking of more powerful EM simulators: the phase center will be somewhere close to the rotational center line of your helix. Mount the helix on a movable guide (e.g. a rod through a pipe with a screw to fix it), and experimentally determine the best location by pointing the dish at a known emitter (if in doubt, the sun) and measuring observed power.

Thank you very much. It seems to really just be easier to build a movable jig.
One more quick question.
I actually found phase info in the far-field data now my question is what the diffrence between the polarization tilt degree and E(Theta) phase and E(Phi) phase is.

Polarization tells you in which direction your E-field points, phase of the E-field tells you which phase the wave has, and Theta and Phi are just the coordinates in the spherical coordinate system.

Okay thank you very much
